# HTML : page development like g mail with out browser vertical scroll bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, email

I am developing CRM project using HTML and CSS. I need to fit my project for all screens  without vertical scroll bar same like g mail. If we observe g mail we have scroll bar only for mail section not for browser. I need too implement same like that. Can anyone please help me how to implement. the page should be fit for all screens means if it is in small screen or big screen or medium screen. Is there any tutorials or any script for calculating height for main content based on browser height.

I attached image. In that header and main content section is there. So I need to set body height based on browser height and as well as I need to calculate each section height each time based on browser as well as inside divisions.

we should not give any fixed height , why because we need to fit the screen for all resolutions like 1366*768 and 1400*968 and 1680*1050 and 1920*1080. So when we are increasing the browser height the DOM height also should be increase as well as decrease.

[image]

Please help me to find this type of development with HTML, CSS , JavaScript and Jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you check how the default height of your element is. With JQuery this can be done like this: var height = $('.classOfYourElement').height(); var currentBrowserHeight = $(window).height(); Then you need to attach a listener to resize Event $(window).resize(function() { // Inside here you are now calculating the difference of the height of the window to the default height of window which you set earlier. this difference you should then apply to the div height :) hope that helps. }); –

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a wrapper around the 5th section and give it a fixed height. 
Then you have to specify the overflow-y value to scroll i guess.

Comment: we should not give any fixed height , why because we need to fit the screen for all resolutions like 1366*768 and 1400*968 and 1680*1050 and 1920*1080. So when we are increasing the browser height the DOM height also should be increase as well as decrease.

Comment: Then you need javascript or jquery to achieve this.

Comment: plz suggest with java script how can I proceed. I am new to the web development. please suggest me a simple examples if you don't mind.

Comment: First you check how the default height of your element is. 
With JQuery this can be done like this:

var height = $('.classOfYourElement').height();
var currentBrowserHeight = $(window).height();

Then you need to attach a listener to resize Event

$(window).resize(function() {
    // Inside here you are now calculating the difference of the height of the window to the default height of window which you set earlier. 
this difference you should then apply to the div height :) hope that helps.
});